# Spring security Version 3.1 - Need to match user using either userPrincipalName without domain added OR sAMAccountName (search filter ?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, spring-security-ldap

All,

Our IT dept has decided to change the suffix of our users in AD by adding a different suffix to the userPrincipalName in AD to the actual domain being used.

e.g. our domain is xxx.com but userPrincipalName is now "usera@zzz.tech" whereas before it was "usera@xxx.com".

The Spring LDAP AD authentication no longer works with this because of this reason I think:
userPrincipalName is built up using name + domain when it tries to authenticate.

I need to override this somehow - but keep with Spring security version 3.1 (ideally !)

This is the security bean we use

```
<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="$websec{authentication.base}" />
    <constructor-arg value="$websec{ldap.providerUrl}" />
    <property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="dataAutomationGrantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
</bean>
```

How can I override this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: You were using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` to match both username and userPrincipalName with xxx.com suffix, but now you need to authenticate using the standard `LdapAuthenticationProvider` so that you can map username with sAMAccoutnName. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html. Maybe as temporary workaround in bean `ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider` you can try to replace the first argument with the new domain hardcoded `<constructor-arg value="zzz.tech" />`.

Comment: Thanks, but the authentication base still needs to remain the same because that is the actual domain.  I need a way of stopping the automatic build up of the userPrincipalName using the domain name

Comment: Ok then just follow the doc for using LdapAuthenticationProvider and update the post if you still need help.

Comment: I think I need to upgrade to Spring Security 3.2.6 ...?   As this has a setSearchFilter method ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: Yes it seems to be an alternative if you can upgrade. But it is not that hard to set the regular ldap provider to work for AD authentication, you just need to use the good attribute mapping (specific to AD) but otherwise it merely the same as authenticating using another ldap server.

Comment: I hadn't realised from your previous comment that you meant to use a DIFFERENT LDAP provider - it wasn't clear.

Comment: No I just meant : use the standard class LdapAuthenticationProvider and follow the documentation using your AD configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up modifying the original Spring code for the class : ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider and changing the method createBindPrincipal to allow a userPrincipalName that has a different domain to the security root
domain to be authorised.

```
/**
 * Create bind principal by appending configured user domain to username if it doesn't already contain a domain.
 *
 * @param username  User name for which to create bind principal.
 *
 * @return username, if configured domain is null or the username already contains a domain; otherwise username
 *         appended with the configured user domain.
 */
String createBindPrincipal(final String username) {
    if (domain == null || username.contains("@")) {
        return username;
    }
    return username + "@" + userDomain;
}
```

Comment: This saved us having to upgrade the Spring versions (for now).