# LDAP AD Spring Security authentication fails when domain does not match userPrincipalName ending

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate against an AD server. It works fine for most environments, but there is an issue when the Domain Name is not the same as the ending of the `userPrincipalName` of individual users.

I have setup the following properties:

```
xxx.api.auth.ad.domain:foo.bar.com
xxx.api.auth.ad.url:ldaps://yyy.foo.bar.com:636
```

And the users have `userPrincipalName` set as `john.doe@bar.com`. Notice the difference with the Domain Name

Then in my `LoginService` I have this:

```java
private AuthResultDto loginAD(LoginDto login) {

    String adDomain = env.getProperty("xxx.api.auth.ad.domain");
    String adUrl = env.getProperty("xxx.api.auth.ad.url");

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = 
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(adDomain, adUrl);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper());

    Authentication auth = provider
            .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getEmail(), login.getPassword()));

    if (!auth.isAuthenticated())
        throw new CustomMessageException("Invalid Login");
...
}
```

In this case, the authentication fails with the message `Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid`.

spring-ldap-core:2.3.2.RELEASE
spring-security-ldap:5.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: This seems to be the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232159/spring-security-version-3-1-need-to-match-user-using-either-userprincipalname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `createBindPrincipal()` inside `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` checks if the `username` ends with the `domain` and if not, it [appends it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L370). This results in the username becoming `john.doe@bar.com@foo.bar.com`

Unfortunately, `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` is final, so cannot override it. The solution we went with is to not pass down the `domain`, but the `rootDN` instead (constructed by copying code from `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`)

```java
private AuthResultDto loginAD(LoginDto login) {

    String adDomain = env.getProperty("xxx.api.auth.ad.domain");
    String adUrl = env.getProperty("xxx.api.auth.ad.url");

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = 
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(null, adUrl, rootDnFromDomain(adDomain));
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper());

    Authentication auth = provider
            .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getEmail(), login.getPassword()));

    if (!auth.isAuthenticated())
        throw new CustomMessageException("Invalid Login");
...
}

// copied from ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
private String rootDnFromDomain(String domain) {
    String[] tokens = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(domain, ".");
    StringBuilder root = new StringBuilder();

    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (root.length() > 0) {
            root.append(',');
        }
        root.append("dc=").append(token);
    }

    return root.toString();
}
```